# Getting an "InvalidUseOfMatchersException", even though it's being used correctly

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following mocked object:

```
@Mock
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Then I'm writing some mocking logic that claim's I'm doing this wrong:

```
Mockito.when(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(Mockito.anyObject())).thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Matcher methods like `anyObject()`, `eq()` **do not** return matchers. Internally, they record a matcher on a stack and return a dummy value (usually null). This implementation is due to static type safety imposed by the java compiler. The consequence is that you cannot use `anyObject()`, `eq()` methods outside of verified/stubbed method.

My suggestino would be to use `any()`

For example

```
@Test
public void TestObjectMapper() {
    //Arrange
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    when(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(any()))
        .thenThrow(new JsonProcessingException());

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using @InjectMocks for the class under test and @Mock for creating and injecting mocks automatically. This works perfectly fine for me.

Something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public final class ClassTest{

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassUnderTest objectOfClass;

    @Mock 
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test (expected = JsonProcessingException.class)
    public void testMethod() {
        when(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(anyObject()))
       .thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
    }
}
```

InvalidUseOfMatchersException can occur if you are not using matchers for all arguments within a function call in a test.

Like:

```
when(mock.doSomething(any(), someMock)).thenReturn(something); // This can generate the exception.
```

What you can use instead is:

```
when(mock.doSomething(any(),eq(someMock))).thenReturn(something); // Here we use eq matcher instead of simply passing the mock
```